# XGBoost training over data shards

Tags: xgboost

I'm new to xgboost, and trying to figure out if there is a possibility to have the algorithm train over sharded data into multiples computing nodes (i.e., data is partitioned over different servers).

As an example, imagine data a dataset.csv is divided into four distinct datasets each residing in a seperate server.
Can we have the algorithm (XGboost) train in parallel over each dataset (running on each machine) and then combine the results?
This would helpful in terms of reducing the overall runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/xgboost4j_spark_tutorial.html suit your use case?

Comment: @jared_mamrot not really, I'm not using spark.